Nuget dependency cannot get resolved
While running automated tests in GitLab pipeline the following error appears

System.Exception: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

After further investigation I found out that there is a missing package

TestPluginDiscoverer: Failed to get types from assembly 'Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client, Version=0.2.6.42401, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf2156ad364e35'. Error: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b1321cd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionFramework.TestPluginDiscoverer.GetTestExtensionsFromAssembly[TPluginInfo,TExtension](Assembly assembly, Dictionary`2 pluginInfos, String filePath)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

This problem only appeared after I added Confluent.Kafka nuget package. I am using .NET 6.
